# Finding Offset using double array and list C#

Tags: c#, arrays

Im trying to find the offset(difference between the array elements) of an array of double..The formula for my offset calculation is Offset= ((double[x+1]-double[x])*33)..
The problem I encounter is I cant seem to display the offsetX. What am I doing wrong here ?
Is there an easier way to do this ?

Here are my codes :

```
//double[] test is an infinite array containing double values that are passed from the Client to Server via UDP
//example : double[] test={1.11,2.344,3.45,4.54,....,......,....}

//Partial codes on the Server side to calculate and display offset

List<double> array = new List<double>();

//Im trying to store just the elements of postion 0,3,6..from the double []test into list array
//ignore array1[] and array2[]

for (int j = 0; j < test.Length;) 
{ 
    array.Add(test[j]); j++;
    array1.Add(test[j]); j++; 
    array2.Add(test[j]); j++;
}

double[] gg = array.ToArray();

//Finding the offset
for (int i = 0, j = 1; i < gg.Length - 1; i++, j++)
{
    offsetX.Add(gg[j] - gg[i]);
    offsetX[i] = Math.Round(offsetX[i], 1);
    offsetX[i] = (offsetX[i] * 33);

}

Console.Write( "OffsetX:" + string.Join(",", offsetX) +"/n");
```

Answer (score 0):

The method below just iterates over the arrays adding the offsets during the initial iteration of the list

```
List<double> array = new List<double>() { 1.11,2.344,3.45,4.54 };

var offsets = new List<double>();
for (int i = 1; i < array.Count; i++)
    offsets.Add(array[i] - array[i-1]);
```

This results in the offsets of:

```
Offsets: 1.234,1.106,1.09
```

Comment: I didn't have an output statement, but the following will display the results: `Console.WriteLine("Offsets:" + string.Join(",", offsets));`

Comment: Yup I did try with an output statement previously...It still didnt work